# php code calculate 30 minutes from created datetime field in table

Tags: php, datetime

In my table there is a **created datetime field** in which data inserting like 2016-05-25 11:50:35.

Suppose my insertion time  is 11:50 and current time is 12:10,so the differnce is 20 mins.
now i need to check is get this difference in one variable and check if differnce > 30 then the edit link will be invisible else visible.

below is my code..

i get extracted mins from my created datetime field from database.

```
$var1 = $post['ShipperRating']['created'];
$time1 = date('i', strtotime($var1)); 
$finaltime = $time1;
echo $finaltime;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$createdDateTime = new DateTime($post['ShipperRating']['created']);
$createdDateTime->modify('+30 minutes');

if ($createdDateTime >= new DateTime()) {
    echo '<a href="/url">Edit</a>';
}
```

Comment: but i ask something different...Matei...i edited my question in clear view with example....please see once again....

Comment: Even if you edited the question it is not clear what you want.. The answer I gave is exactly for what I understand from your question.. be more specific to make me understand your needs..

Comment: Do you mean you want to display that link every day for 30 minutes? or only once.. after the creation date? because my answer is exactly you need for the second question

Answer (score 0):

Using strtotime (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will work...

```
$var1 = $post['ShipperRating']['created'];
$time1 = strtotime($var1);
$finaltime = strtotime('+ 30 minutes',$time1);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$finaltime);
```

Comment: but i ask something different.i edited my question in clear view with example....please see once again.

Comment: sure, you edited it after I answered... it happens :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it by PHP then you have to refresh page after 30 minutes to and calculate the time from server which already show in other answers. You can use header function to set time for refreshing page

```
header("Refresh: 300;url='http://example.com/example'");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use following Function 
(1800000 miliseconds =30mintues)

```
window.setTimeout('removelink()',1800000); //
function removelink()
{
    //write Code to Remove your Link
}
```